# Hiding multiple rows in multiple sheets using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote some code a couple of years ago that hides rows in multiple sheets based on criteria from a single sheet. The code has worked well, but I'm wanting to add a couple of new sheets and, following the same (messy) code that I've written, the macro gets too large and I get a compile error ("Procedure too large"). I'm certain there is a much better, cleaner, and smaller way to do this but I'm still pretty green when it comes to code and haven't been able to make anything else work. Below is a sample of the code I have for a single line. This is multiplied ~60 times for the following ranges in this worksheet: B12:B31, B36:B65, B70:B79, B84:B88. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

```
If Target.Address = "$B$12" Then
    Rows("13").EntireRow.Hidden = (Target.Value = "" And Range("B13") = "")
End If
If Target.Address = "$B$12" Then
    Worksheets("CS Personnel").Rows("13").EntireRow.Hidden = (Target.Value = "" And Range("B13") = "")
End If
If Target.Address = "$B$12" Then
    Worksheets("NSF Condensed").Rows("4").EntireRow.Hidden = (Target.Value = "")
End If
If Target.Address = "$B$12" Then
    Worksheets("Basic Budget").Rows("4").EntireRow.Hidden = (Target.Value = "")
End If
If Target.Address = "$B$12" Then
    Worksheets("Basic Budget").Rows("58").EntireRow.Hidden = (Target.Value = "")
End If
If Target.Address = "$B$12" Then
    Worksheets("Basic Budget").Rows("113").EntireRow.Hidden = (Target.Value = "")
End If
If Target.Address = "$B$12" Then
    Worksheets("Hourly Budget").Rows("4").EntireRow.Hidden = (Target.Value = "")
End If
If Target.Address = "$B$12" Then
    Worksheets("Hourly Budget").Rows("58").EntireRow.Hidden = (Target.Value = "")
End If
If Target.Address = "$B$12" Then
    Worksheets("Hourly Budget").Rows("113").EntireRow.Hidden = (Target.Value = "")
End If
If Target.Address = "$B$12" Then
    Worksheets("Burdened Budget").Rows("4").EntireRow.Hidden = (Target.Value = "")
End If
If Target.Address = "$B$12" Then
    Worksheets("Burdened Budget").Rows("54").EntireRow.Hidden = (Target.Value = "")
End If
If Target.Address = "$B$12" Then
    Worksheets("Burdened Budget").Rows("105").EntireRow.Hidden = (Target.Value = "")
End If
If Target.Address = "$B$12" Then
    Worksheets("Hourly Budget (Burdened)").Rows("4").EntireRow.Hidden = (Target.Value = "")
End If
If Target.Address = "$B$12" Then
    Worksheets("Hourly Budget (Burdened)").Rows("54").EntireRow.Hidden = (Target.Value = "")
End If
If Target.Address = "$B$12" Then
    Worksheets("Hourly Budget (Burdened)").Rows("105").EntireRow.Hidden = (Target.Value = "")
End If
```

Comment: You only need one If Target.Address = "$B$12" Then for a start and have the actions within that If block as you perform them all and you are better storing rows within the same sheet in a range variable and hiding that range in one go where you have same boolean test.  (Target.Value = "")

Comment: multiple rows with a range e.g. Worksheets("Basic Budget").Range("4:4,58:58,113:113").   But that said, I am not sure if this question fits with the scope of SO as defined in the Help info

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you use one column in all the sheets where you specify if the specific row that needs to be hidden? For instance, if you fill in a "1" in column A of each row that needs to be hidden, you can use a loop to hide the sheets:

```
    Dim ws as worksheet
    For each ws in thisworkbook.sheets
        for i = 1 to ws.cells(rows.count,1).end(xlup).row
             if ws.cells(i,1).value = 1 then 
                 ws.cells(i,1).entirerow.hidden =  true
             end if
        next i
   next ws
```

Comment: good idea. using worksheet formulas to set the row as TRUE / FALSE for show and then running a loop on it seems way more design efficient.

Comment: This makes way more sense then what I was doing! I'll try to rework it today and let you know how it works. Thanks for your thoughts!

Comment: This worked beautifully for hiding rows. I added to the code to try to get it to also unhide the rows if not =1  but now I get the following error: "Unable to set the Hidden property of Range class" I don't have any objects and the sheet isn't currently protected. perhaps this is a different issue now. I'll have to get back at it on Monday to see if I can figure out why it doesn't like that bit of code. Here;s the code I added just before the "end if"
 Else:ws.cells(i,1).entirerow.hidden =  false